When did we start utilizing squiggles/waves to demonstrate where water is?
I have been trying to research the history of cartographic maps symbols.
However, I have been struggling to find when symbols for bodies of water came about.
Where/When did we start utilizing squiggles and/or waves as map symbols for bodies of water? Was it a common symbol in ancient map making?

Without claiming a direct connection, the egypt hieroglyph "n"  (Gardiner N35) is a squiggly line and described as a "ripple of water". As a determinative for liquid and water,  (Gardiner N35a) three lines of ripples are used.

I'm having trouble verifying the vintage of this particular feature, but what I can find of Tabula Peutingeriana (from possibly as old as the 6th century?) shows seas not as a solid color, but rather a series of  tightly-thatched diagonal lines, that kind of has the effect you are talking about.

@T.E.D. The oldest known copy, as the WP article states, is a parchment from the 12th century. The Austrian National Library presents digital reproductions of that exemplar. Water is represented as solid color. The hatchings you saw were added by the printer of the 19th century reproduction.
